# ¿Como chequear si una habitacion esta disponible?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, uml

tengo una base de datos que con 6 tablas `T_cliente`, `T_hotel`,`T_reserva`,`T_tarcre`,`T_tarifa` y `T_tiphab`.

Aca esta el diagrama UML. Lo que no se como hacer, es chequear si la habitacion esta disponible o no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Tabla T_Reserva

fechaLlegada: Date
numNoches: integer
numAdultos: integer
numMenDos: integer
numMenDosDoce: integer
TarjetaCrédito
Cliente
TipoHabitación
Tarifa
Reserva
Hotel
localizador: String
observaciones: String
precio: Double
régimen: String
codCliente: String
codHotel: String
tipoHab: String
Clave primaria: localizador
Clave foránea hacia T_Cliente codCliente
Clave foránea hacia T_Hotel codHotel
Clave foránea hacia T_TipHab tipoHab, codHotel
Clave foránea hacia T_Tarifa fechaLlegada, regimen, tipoHab, codHotel
Como clave primaria alternativa tenemos, codigoHotel, codigoCliente,
FechaLlegada, pero de esta manera sólo puede haber un reserva para un cliente en
una fecha determinada.

Tabla T_Cliente

codCliente: String
nombre: String
apellido: String
dirección: String
provincia: String
país: String
código postal: String
teléfono: String
móvil: String
email: String
Clave primaria: codCliente
Tabla T_TarCre
número: String
caducidad: String
tipo: String
codCliente: String
Clave primaria: número
Clave foránea hacia T_Cliente codCliente

Tabla T_Hotel

codigoHotel: String
Nombre: String
fechaMaxEntrada: Date
numMaxNoches : integer
Clave primaria: codHotel 



Tabla T_TipHab

tipo: String
numMáxPersonas: integer
disponibilidad: integer
codHotel: String
precio: real
Clave primaria: tipo, codHotel
Clave foránea hacia T_Hotel codHotel

Tabla T_Tarifa

precioNoche: Double
fechaInicio: Date
fechaFin: Date
regimen: String
tarifa: Double
codHotel: String
tipoHab: String
Clave primaria: fechaInicio, regimen, tipoHab, codHotel,
Clave foránea hacia T_TipHab tipoHab, codHotel
```

Comment: No has realizado algún script para esto?

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría es de la fecha de entrada sumarle los días reservados, asi tendras la fecha de entrada y fecha de salida. Así cuando hagas tu consulta de comparación usaras dichas fechas para evaluar si esta o no ocupada.

```
declare @Vfechaentrada date, @Vfechasalida date

declare @reservaciones table (
habitacion int,
fechaentrada date,
fechasalida date
)

select @Vfechaentrada=getdate() , @Vfechasalida=DATEADD (day , 4 , GETDATE() ) 

insert into @reservaciones
(habitacion,fechaentrada,fechasalida)
select 101,@Vfechaentrada,@Vfechasalida

--intentar reservar el 14 de diciembre

declare @fecha   date='14/12/2017'

select COUNT(1) as libre from @reservaciones where @fecha between  @Vfechaentrada and @Vfechasalida
```

Es una idea, solo tendrías que depurarla.

Comment: No se como usar variables y funciones en SQL... algun tuto para guiarme... ?

Comment: En esta página puedes aprender mucho. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: `getDate()` funciona en `SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2005` yo estoy usando `mariadb ` no se si en esos motores tienen mariadb incluido..

Comment: Aquí puedes guiarte para MySql https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_mysql.asp en Mysql getdate() es Now()

Comment: `select COUNT(1) as libre` no tengo una tabla  `libre` en la base de datos.. como seria en mi base de datos..

Comment: Libre es un alias para el resultado. Si haces una consulta escalar, puedes asignarle a una variable el resultado del count, si count > 0 entonces habitacion está ocupada.

Comment: ok.. ya entendi gracias...

Comment: De nada, a la orden. Estamos para ayudar, así como a mi me han ayudado aquí.

Comment: Una pregunta..¿ Como puedo usar el script en un servlet ? .. ya que uso `PreparedStatment` el cual usa placeholders (`?`)..

Comment: Para evitar que te pongan votos negativos, abre un nuevo tema con esa pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Ahi lo hice: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124421/consulta-sql-para-verificar-habitaciones-libres-con-preparedstatement-en-java