# Consulta SQL para verificar habitaciones libres con PreparedStatement en Java

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, servlets

Tengo esta consulta que me la paso @raintrooper, en esta otra consulta que hice [¿Como chequear si una habitacion esta disponible?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124222/como-chequear-si-una-habitacion-esta-disponible):

```
declare @Vfechaentrada date, @Vfechasalida date

declare @reservaciones table (
habitacion int,
fechaentrada date,
fechasalida date
)

select @Vfechaentrada=getdate() , @Vfechasalida=DATEADD (day , 4 , GETDATE() ) 

insert into @reservaciones
(habitacion,fechaentrada,fechasalida)
select 101,@Vfechaentrada,@Vfechasalida

--intentar reservar el 14 de diciembre

declare @fecha   date='14/12/2017'

select COUNT(1) as libre from @reservaciones where @fecha between  @Vfechaentrada and @Vfechasalida
```

¿Como puedo usar los placeholders de `PreparedStatement` en Java con esta consulta?..

Gracias.

Estos son los datos que voy usar:

```
 Tabla T_Reserva

fechaLlegada: Date
numNoches: integer
numAdultos: integer
numMenDos: integer
numMenDosDoce: integer
TarjetaCrédito
Cliente
TipoHabitación
Tarifa
Reserva
Hotel
localizador: String
observaciones: String
precio: Double
régimen: String
codCliente: String
codHotel: String
tipoHab: String
Clave primaria: localizador
Clave foránea hacia T_Cliente codCliente
Clave foránea hacia T_Hotel codHotel
Clave foránea hacia T_TipHab tipoHab, codHotel
Clave foránea hacia T_Tarifa fechaLlegada, regimen, tipoHab, codHotel
Como clave primaria alternativa tenemos, codigoHotel, codigoCliente,
FechaLlegada, pero de esta manera sólo puede haber un reserva para un cliente en
una fecha determinada.

Tabla T_Cliente

codCliente: String
nombre: String
apellido: String
dirección: String
provincia: String
país: String
código postal: String
teléfono: String
móvil: String
email: String
Clave primaria: codCliente
Tabla T_TarCre
número: String
caducidad: String
tipo: String
codCliente: String
Clave primaria: número
Clave foránea hacia T_Cliente codCliente

Tabla T_Hotel

codigoHotel: String
Nombre: String
fechaMaxEntrada: Date
numMaxNoches : integer
Clave primaria: codHotel 



Tabla T_TipHab

tipo: String
numMáxPersonas: integer
disponibilidad: integer
codHotel: String
precio: real
Clave primaria: tipo, codHotel
Clave foránea hacia T_Hotel codHotel

Tabla T_Tarifa

precioNoche: Double
fechaInicio: Date
fechaFin: Date
regimen: String
tarifa: Double
codHotel: String
tipoHab: String
Clave primaria: fechaInicio, regimen, tipoHab, codHotel,
Clave foránea hacia T_TipHab tipoHab, codHotel
```

Comment: ¿Qué datos son los que vas a usar desde Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esa consulta es una prueba de concepto, por lo que asumo que querrás usarlo en producción en tablas reales. Deberás usar algo similar a esto:

```
/* La conexión la tenemos definida en "con" */
PreparedStatement busquedaStmt = null;
String busquedaString = "SELECT COUNT(*) libre " +
  "FROM reservas " +
  "WHERE habitacion = ? AND ? BETWEEN fechaentrada AND fechasalida";
try {
  /* Si sólo queremos consultar la disponibilidad pero aún no
     queremos hacer efectiva la reserva no necesitamos una transacción */
  con.setAutoCommit(true);
  busquedaStmt = con.prepareStatement(busquedaString);
  /* Asignamos las variables a los "?" de la consulta SQL */
  busquedaStmt.setInt(1, habitacion);
  busquedaStmt.setString(2, fecha);
  /* Ejecutamos la consulta */
  ResultSet rs = busquedaStmt.executeQuery();
  while (rs.next()) {
    /* Obtenemos el único campo del único resultado */
    int libre = rs.getInt("libre");
    /* Hacemos lo que tengamos que hacer con el resultado */
    /* ... */
  }
} catch (SQLException e) {
  /* ... */
} finally {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: porque en `libre` es `-1` y no `1` o `2`...

Comment: Es algo arbitrario. Podría definirse a 0 o sin valor y que el código que use "libre" esté dentro del bloque `try/catch`.

Comment: Una pregunta ¿No falta el `con.commit();` ?

Comment: Claro lo lei de ahi ..por eso me surgio la pregunta ..por que en el codigo del linl habia un commit ..pero ahora me quedo claro gracias...

Comment: Hola @TOMAS , he editado mi respuesta de acuerdo a tu última edición de la pregunta. Por una errata ayer dejé `con.setAutoCommit(false);` cuando lo que quería era ponerlo a `true`. Ahora entiendo el sentido de tus preguntas. Cuando quieras hacer consultas y no hacer modificaciones no necesitas usar transacciones, por lo que lo puedes desactivar. Cuando quieras hacer efectiva la reserva sí que deberás hacer una transacción para que se quede bloqueado el registro hasta que decidas hacer o no la reserva si está disponible la habitación.

Comment: Pero por default no esta en true el autocommit ..??

Comment: Sí, pero nunca sabes qué consulta ni qué código se ha ejecutado anteriormente, así que a mí siempre me gusta asegurarme que funcionará como espero.

Comment: No entiendo a que te referis con  `nunca sabes qué consulta ni qué código se ha ejecutado anteriormente`

Comment: Tu aplicación hará más consultas en otras zonas de tu código, algunas de ellas requerirán activar las transacciones (desactivar autocommit). Entonces no está de más asegurarte que la opción está configurada como esperas antes de hacer consultas SQL.

Comment: ¿Te resolvió esta respuesta la pregunta?

Comment: SI...el tema es que estoy haciendo un DAO... y estoy viendo donde meto los metodos `doPost` y `doGet`..

Comment: Pero ¿es una nueva pregunta? No veo nada de lo que comentas en la pregunta actual. Si tu duda de los marcadores ha sido resuelta deberías marcarlo así.

Answer (score 2):

Como bien respondió OscarGarcia con respecto el código de java puedes basarte en esa forma de programación, entonces para abonar a la solución si tienes mas dudas puedes revisar este enlace que he creado http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb4152/3, en el puedes realizar consultas sql en linea y compartirlas, ademas ya tiene el schema de base de datos según el ejemplo que presentas.

Como recomendación debes agregar en el SQL el número de la habitación que deseas consultar de lo contrario cuando quieras buscar una reserva para la habitación 1 el SQL buscara instancias para cualquier habitación por ejemplo con los siguientes datos.

```
INSERT INTO `reservaciones` (`habitacion`, `fechaentrada`, `fechasalida`) 
VALUES
('1', '2017-12-14', '2017-12-18'),
('1', '2017-12-19', '2017-12-21'),
('2', '2017-12-14', '2017-12-15'),
('3', '2017-12-14', '2017-12-15');

Select count(*) from reservaciones where '2017-12-15' BETWEEN fechaentrada 
AND fechasalida; -- dará come resultado 3

Select count(*) from reservaciones where habitacion = 1 AND '2017-12-15' 
BETWEEN fechaentrada AND fechasalida; -- dará como resultado 1

en java seria: SELECT COUNT(*) libre FROM reservas WHERE habitacion = ? AND ? BETWEEN fechaentrada AND fechasalida; -- tener en cuenta que el segundo ? debe ser un tipo de dato Date en java.
```

todo esto lo puedes experimentar en linea con el link que he colocado anteriormente y así te sera mas fácil plantear nuevas dudas a futuro.